# Regex: recursively search contents and return results

Tags: regex, osx-mavericks

I have several JavaScript source files which call a certain function.

```
function foo( param ) {
   findMe( 'foo' );
   findMe('bar');
}

function bar() {
   findMe("baz"); dontFindMe(); findMe( "blah"  );
}

findMe("foobar");
```

I want to search the files for calls to this function and return the parameters that are passed. This might not seem like something useful, but trust me - it is, I just simplified the example :)

The result should look like this:

```
foo
bar
baz
blah
foobar
```

This is what I got so far:

```
13:46:39 ~ > grep -o findMe\([[:space:]]*[\'\"].*[\'\"][[:space:]]*\) ~/Desktop/greptest.txt 
findMe( 'foo' )
findMe('bar')
findMe("baz"); dontFindMe(); findMe( "blah"  )
findMe("foobar")
```

But now, I'm running out of ideas. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm running Mavericks with grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD.

Thanks in advance!

// edit

Thanks to Vasili for the correct regex and to Abhiskek for pointing me towards sed. This is my solution:

```
14:51:21 ~ > grep -o -E "findMe\(\s*('|\")([^)]+)\1\s*\)" Desktop/greptest.txt | sed "s/findMe([[:space:]]*[\"']\([a-z]*\)[\"'][[:space:]]*)/\1/g"

foo
bar
baz
blah
foobar
```

Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: No idea about grep, however `findMe\((.+?)\)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regular Expression

```
findMe\(\s*('|")([^)]+)\1\s*\)
```

### Explanation

- `\(` : open parenthesis.
- `\s*('|")` : match whitespace(or nothing) followed by a quote (single or double) and backreference it with group 1.
- `([^)]+)` : match anything that isn't a closing parenthesis and backreference it group 2 **(this is what you want to put into an array.)**
- `\1\s*` : match the first capture group, so we have consistent quote marks. Followed by whitespace(or nothing)
- `\)` : close parenthesis.

### Online example:

[**Regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/eK8jL5)

### Why you should use this regex

- The use of backreferences means you will match parameters that are inside consistent quotation marks, Example: you won't match this: `findMe('foo")` because the quotes are different.
- Matching everything that isn't a closing parenthesis `([^)]+)` ensures that your regex does not overextend past the parameter and into another functions parameter, for example, you will NOT match this: `findMe('foo) accident ')`

Comment: Answer has been modified with capture group(s)

Answer (score 0):

A bit complicated but if you are sure that your parameters do not contain the ';' character, you can first replace it with a '\n' character, perform grep as before and the pipe it to sed with backreferences.

```
sed 's/;/\n/g' ~/Desktop/greptest.txt 
| grep -o findMe\([[:space:]]*[\'\"].*[\'\"][[:space:]]*\)
| sed 's/\(.*findMe( "*\)\(.*\)\(" *)\).*/\2/g'
```

Demo file:

```
aksdbajksbd
alsdnlkasnd
asfindMe( "bar"  );alsndkfindMe( "baz" );sdasd
asdadsads
asdad
```

Output:

```
bar
baz
```